# How to make Tor use italian only proxy?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, configuration, circuit, firefox

I need Tor to use proxy only from Italy,how can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean entry nodes (the one you connect to) or exit nodes (the one the web server sees)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean not "proxy", but instead "exit node"...

First, know that restricting your exit nodes to a small subset can reduce your anonymity set and make you easier to unmask.

An actual proxy or VPN that terminates within the country you want (Italy) may be a better (faster, more sure) option for you.

If you do need the Tor anonymity capabilities which still remain after you restrict your exit nodes, then you can try to set options to make Tor select exit nodes only from a given country.

A couple caveats:  Tor sometimes knows, via 3rd party geolocation data, which nodes are in which country's IP space.  A country's IP space may or may not correspond to the physical location of the machines using those IPs.

To make Tor use Italian ({it}) label exit nodes, put "ExitNodes {it}" in your Tor Browser Bundle's configuration file.  As noted above, these exit nodes may not actually be in Italy, but the odds are OK that they are.  Note that you will likely find more exit nodes labeled {us} and {de} than {it}.